# vSphere Web Client Object properties

Tags: apache-flex, vmware, vsphere

In vSphere web client extension development , i want to fetch the properties of VM , In the sample code model they are adding some annotations like

```
[Model(property="name")]
    /**
     * The name of this VirtualMachine.
     */
    public var name:String;
```

Where can i get the List of available properties for all objects (like vm  , datastore , hosts)

Comment: Does this relate to Adobe/Apache Flex [the UI Framework] in any way?

Comment: Presuming that the questioner is asking about vSphere 5.1 or later, it (kind of) does.  The vSphere 5.1 web client is written in Flex, and extensions to it are also written in Flex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming that you're talking about building an extension for the vSphere 5.1 web client, the documentation has a [list of extension points](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.wcsdk.pg.doc/ExtPtList_Appendix.html#990212).  Listing the properties for each type of object would be far outside the scope of an answer here, so I'll instead point you to the vSphere 5.1 SDK documentation, specifically the [appendix listing all properties](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/properties-landing.html).

If you're new to vSphere web client extension development, a good starting point is the [What’s New In vSphere 5.1 API, vSphere Web Client SDK & vCenter SSO SDK](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/09/whats-new-in-vsphere-5-1-api-vsphere-web-client-sdk-vcenter-sso-sdk.html) blog post.  I see that you've already posted the [same question](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/457184) in the [VMware Communities](https://communities.vmware.com/welcome), so I don't need to point you there.

Answer (score 0):

The properties correspond to the properties of Managed and Data Objects as described in the vSphere Managment SDK documentation. In particular the example you gave corresponds to Managed Object *VirtualMachine*'s *name* property. Since VirtualMachine inherits from ManagedEntity, this is where the *name* property is actually defined (see http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc%2Fvim.ManagedEntity.html for details). You can also use *property.paths.into.data.objects* to access properties of nested data objects.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get list of vm or datastore... you can use DataServiceProvider get data with a simple constraint